# IntelliJ "cannot find class" on build despite added as "compile" module

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I added some sources as a module and in the actual Java file, it shows as found without an error: `public class MyClass extends SomeClass`. There's no red line and "ctrl + spacebar" shows the class and its package.

But when I choose to build the project, it throws the error:

```
Error:(25, 31) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SomeClass
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Does the module containing `MyClass` have `SomeClass` declared as a dependency?

Comment: @hexafraction i believe so. it's added as a module and set to "compile" under the MyClass's module. is that what you mean?